# Does the Trimble GeoXT 2008 (3000 series) work with ArcPad 10?

Tags: arcpad, trimble

I've been looking around and I've found some info on the 6000 series...however, nothing much on the 3000 series.

My main concern is the firmware on the GeoXT 3000 is not compatible with the ArcPad 10.x and that it won't be able to run. Before I try going to knock down Trimble's customer service door, does anyone here have experience with using ArcPad 10.x on a GeoXT 3000?

Comment: Will this help you? https://geonet.esri.com/thread/48463

Comment: thank you Stefan! At least I know someone out there has ArcPad 10 on their unit, so I should be able to do it on my own. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your welcome! Can you please mark this answer?

Answer (score 1):

ArcPad uses NMEA (maybe some proprietary formats as well, but not Trimble formats) - Geo 2008 puts out NMEA on port Com 2 and ArcPad will automatically detect this.  No problem using ArcPad 10 on Geo 2008 (renamed to Geo 3000).

If you use ArcPad with Geo 2008, use the (free) Trimble GPS Controller on the Geo 2008 to set up real-time corrections (SBAS or NTRIP) to get better real-time accuracy.

If you want higher post-processed accuracy from Geo 2008 and ArcPad, Trimble sells Trimble Positions ArcPad Extension but since you are using an XT (single frequency) unit, post-processing is probably not worth the cost of a TPAe license!